# $stateProvider get $stateParams in .go()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wanna access some parameters for a `$state`:

```
$state.go('tabs.foobar', { go: 'yo' });
```

So I can access the "go" parameter, and alert the 'yo'.

```
.controller('foobarCtrl', function($scope, $window, $stateParams) {
    if($stateParams.go) {
      alert($stateParams.go);
    }
```

But it's not working with the $stateProvider, what am I missing?

```
$stateProvider.state('tabs.foobar', {
  url: '/foobar',
  cache: false,
  views: {
    'tab3': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/foobar.html',
      controller: 'foobarCtrl'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried declaring `go` as a parameter of the `tabs.foobar` state? [Only registered params will show up](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#important-stateparams-gotcha)

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare the `go` parameter as a URL Path or query parameter:

```
url: '/foobar/:go',
```

OR

```
url: '/foobar?go',
```